# Structure of an app, activity and fragment

Tags: android, xml, android-activity, fragment, structure

I have a (maybe stupid) question.
I'm in this scenario.

[image]

As you can see in the image, I have structured my app on three activities but if i want to open, for example, my ACTIVITY2 from a button in the MAIN activity, the opening is very slow.. it takes about 1-3 seconds (Is because the activity2 layout is heavy?). 
The same situation there is if I open the OPTION activity but in this case the opening take about 0.5-1 seconds.

If you were me, how would you have structured the app? Which is the best way?

For example, when in facebook app you tap your profile button, starts a new activity or it's a fragment?

**UPDATE #1:**
I have tried to transform the options activity to a fragment, in this way:

[image]

And now the intent take about 0.3 second at the first opening and it's instantaneous for the next. Could be a good way?

**UPDATE #2:**

I have discovered (with the traceview) that initialize

```
SharedPreferences preferences = new SecurePreferences(context);
```

take long time! I use this library to encrypt my SharedPreferences [(SecurePreferences Lib)](https://github.com/scottyab/secure-preferences)

If I remove this line opening is about 2 seconds faster. I hope this will help someone, but I'm not sure that this is the main problem..

Comment: Do you use any sources to pull data to be displayed in the Activity2 . Are you using emulator or a device? what is the device?

Comment: I'm using Galaxy S4 with android 5.0.1

Comment: Do you use any sources to pull data to be displayed in the Activity2?

Comment: What do you mean with "Do you use any sources" ?
I'm sorry but I don't understand.
If do you want to know if I put some data in the intent or if I have to do some elaboration before to display data the answer is no.. At the moment in the java code of MAIN there is only the intent and in the java code of ACTIVITY2 there is nothing

Comment: I think you are using android studio, Are you running it on debug mode? or are just running it?

Comment: I use run mode, not debug mode